# Magento create session when browser is closed

Tags: magento-1.9, session, core-session

How to create session in magento which will be destroyed when browser gets closed and gets created again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you are referring to but persistent cookies are supported by default in Magento 1.9. You can find details about it here in the official documentation: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/sales/shopping-cart-persistent.html

To configure them, you can follow this guide: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/sales/shopping-cart-persistent-setup.html